# Loop through json file to create html and output html using javascript (using fetch)

Tags: javascript, r

I am unable to output the html elements created within this for loop, however I am able to log the html without an issue.

Google searching / Youtube searching how to read in a json file and loop through it to create html on a webpage has given me very poor results. I would like to read the data in ideally as a const, that I can access everywhere throughout my code and just simply loop through it. It appears fetch() is the current common way of doing this in JS if I limit my results to past year. Unfortunately fetch is returning some sort of async promise which just makes things more confusing. XMLHttpRequest() is another method I tried doing this with no luck, also my code entirely changes using that method. I would expect the code to look something like the R header, but I cannot find anything like this in JS.

## JS

```
fetch('/reports.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      
var j;
for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
var sec = document.createElement('section');
var t = document.createElement('table');
var tb = document.createElement('tbody');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');

var d1 = document.createElement('div');
d1.className = 'categories';

var d1_a = document.createElement('a');
d1_a.innerText = 'Equity';
d1_a.href = '/report/equity.html';
d1_a.target = '_self';

var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var h1_a = document.createElement('a');
h1_a.innerText = data[j].tickers
h1_a.href = data[j].urls
h1_a.target = '_self';

var d2 = document.createElement('div');
var d2_author = document.createElement('span');
var d2_date = document.createElement('span');
d2_author.innerText = data[j].authors
d2_date.innerText = data[j].dates

var sum = document.createElement('div');
sum.className = 'summary';
sum.innerText = data[j].contents

var spacer = document.createElement('td');
spacer.className = 'spacer spacer-right';

var sidetitle = document.createElement('td');
sidetitle.className = 'side-title';
var sidetitle_h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var sidetitle_a = document.createElement('a');
sidetitle_a.innerText = "Report";
sidetitle_a.href = '/report/reports.html';
sidetitle_a.target = '_self';
    
t.appendChild(tb);
tb.appendChild(tr);
tr.appendChild(td);
td.appendChild(d1);
td.appendChild(h1);
td.appendChild(d2);
td.appendChild(sum);
h1.appendChild(h1_a);
d1.appendChild(d1_a);
d2.appendChild(d2_date);
d2.appendChild(d2_author);
tr.appendChild(spacer);
tr.appendChild(sidetitle);
sidetitle.appendChild(sidetitle_h1);
sidetitle_h1.appendChild(sidetitle_a);

sec2 = t, tb, tr, td
sec.appendChild(sec2);
sec.className = 'article-list post-card';

console.log(j)
console.log(sec)
document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(sec); 
};
});
```

## JSON

```
[{"tickers":"AAPL","dates":"2021-06-05","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for AAPL containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/aapl-financial-report.html"},{"tickers":"GOOG","dates":"2021-06-05","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for GOOG containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/goog-financial-report.html"},{"tickers":"NFLX","dates":"2021-06-01","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for NFLX containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/nflx-financial-report.html"},{"tickers":"AMZN","dates":"2021-06-01","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for AMZN containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/amzn-financial-report.html"}]
```

The app div is not missing and I'm able to output this information properly if I create individual arrays for each element (tickers, authors, dates, urls, contents).

## JS hardcoded that works

```
var tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'NFLX', 'AMZN'];
var dates = ['2021-06-05', '2021-06-05', '2021-06-01', '2021-06-01'];
var authors = [' someone', ' someone', ' someone', ' someone'];
var contents = ['Financial report for AAPL containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics', 'Financial report for GOOG containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics', 'Financial report for NFLX containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics', 'Financial report for AMZN containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics'];
var urls = ['report/aapl-financial-report.html', 'report/goog-financial-report.html', 'report/nflx-financial-report.html', 'report/amzn-financial-report.html'];

var j;
for (j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
var sec = document.createElement('section');
var t = document.createElement('table');
var tb = document.createElement('tbody');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');

var d1 = document.createElement('div');
d1.className = 'categories';

var d1_a = document.createElement('a');
d1_a.innerText = 'Equity';
d1_a.href = '/report/equity.html';
d1_a.target = '_self';

var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var h1_a = document.createElement('a');
h1_a.innerText = tickers[j]
h1_a.href = urls[j]
h1_a.target = '_self';

var d2 = document.createElement('div');
var d2_author = document.createElement('span');
var d2_date = document.createElement('span');
d2_author.innerText = authors[j]
d2_date.innerText = dates[j]

var sum = document.createElement('div');
sum.className = 'summary';
sum.innerText = contents[j]

var spacer = document.createElement('td');
spacer.className = 'spacer spacer-right';

var sidetitle = document.createElement('td');
sidetitle.className = 'side-title';
var sidetitle_h1 = document.createElement('h1');
var sidetitle_a = document.createElement('a');
sidetitle_a.innerText = "Report";
sidetitle_a.href = '/report/reports.html';
sidetitle_a.target = '_self';

t.appendChild(tb);
tb.appendChild(tr);
tr.appendChild(td);
td.appendChild(d1);
td.appendChild(h1);
td.appendChild(d2);
td.appendChild(sum);
h1.appendChild(h1_a);
d1.appendChild(d1_a);
d2.appendChild(d2_date);
d2.appendChild(d2_author);
tr.appendChild(spacer);
tr.appendChild(sidetitle);
sidetitle.appendChild(sidetitle_h1);
sidetitle_h1.appendChild(sidetitle_a);

sec2 = t, tb, tr, td
sec.appendChild(sec2);
sec.className = 'article-list post-card';

console.log(j)
console.log(sec)
document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(sec); 
};
});
```

## R

```
//#some basic function to read in json data and make available throughout code
json_data = fromJSON('/reports.json')

//#an empty place (array, data.frame, list..etc to collect results from for loop) 
loop = list()

for(i in 1:length(json_data$tickers)) {

  .... code to build all the html elements above

  sec = all the above html elements combind
  
  loop[[i]] = sec

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript has a different focus than R. Javascript specializes in manipulating web pages and so idiomatic Javascript tends to be more succinct when doing that.

The two pieces of Javascript you provide do not appear to have a meaningful difference so I'm not sure why they would behave differently for you. Perhaps `/reports.json` isn't returning the content you think it should be returning?

I would use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to form the html as it's more readable and quite a bit faster than trying to assemble the elements manually.

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) allows you to convert one array into another. In this case, we take each element of the data's root array and convert it into the needed html. (The R package, [purrr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr), adds similar capability.)

[`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) objects (and its [`.createContextualFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) method) are a nifty tool. Created via [`.createRange()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createRange), they allow you to convert html into the actual elements all at once while also acting as a disposable wrapper for those elements. This wrapper gets discarded automatically in the process of appending it as a child.

```js
const app = document.querySelector('#app');
fetch('/reports.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // convert the data to html
    const chunk = data.map(item => 
`<section>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="categories"><a href="/report/equity.html" target="_self">Equity</a></div>
          <h1><a href="${item.urls}" target="_self">${item.tickers}</a></h1>
          <div><span>${item.authors}</span><span>${item.dates}</span></div>
          <div class="summary">${item.contents}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="spacer spacer-right"></td>
        <td class="side-title">
          <h1><a href="/report/reports.html" target="_self">Report</a></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>`
    ).join('');
    // create a virtual container
    const range = document.createRange();
    // give it a context
    range.selectNode(app);
    // add the html, this converts the html into a collection of elements
    const fragment = range.createContextualFragment(chunk);
    // append the elements to the document
    app.appendChild(fragment);
  }));
```

And a demo using your dummy data:

```js
(data => {
    // convert the data to html
    const chunk = data.map(item => 
`<section>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="categories"><a href="/report/equity.html" target="_self">Equity</a></div>
          <h1><a href="${item.urls}" target="_self">${item.tickers}</a></h1>
          <div><span>${item.authors}</span><span>${item.dates}</span></div>
          <div class="summary">${item.contents}</div>
        </td>
        <td class="spacer spacer-right"></td>
        <td class="side-title">
          <h1><a href="/report/reports.html" target="_self">Report</a></h1>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>`
    ).join('');
    // create a virtual container
    const range = document.createRange();
    // give it a context
    range.selectNode(app);
    // add the html, this converts the html into a collection of elements
    const fragment = range.createContextualFragment(chunk);
    // append the elements to the document
    app.appendChild(fragment);
})([{"tickers":"AAPL","dates":"2021-06-05","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for AAPL containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/aapl-financial-report.html"},{"tickers":"GOOG","dates":"2021-06-05","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for GOOG containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/goog-financial-report.html"},{"tickers":"NFLX","dates":"2021-06-01","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for NFLX containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/nflx-financial-report.html"},{"tickers":"AMZN","dates":"2021-06-01","authors":" Someone","contents":"Financial report for AMZN containing financials, sentiment, and portfolio metrics","urls":"report/amzn-financial-report.html"}]
);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Yes there was no meaningful difference between the two js code chunks. The only challenge was the fetch method was returning a promise and not outputting the html in sec which was throwing me for a loop. The template literals is a much better and cleaner way of doing this. Thank you for taking the time to write out all that html!